# How do I send message from c# form application to Socket.io application

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, tcp

I found these two examples on net one is [socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/tree/master/examples/chat) application and second is [c# form application](http://www.csharp-tutorials.info/2016/12/client-server-programming-in-c-chat.html) which are server client based  applications which works fine but when I try to establish communication between c# form application and socket.io application I can not see messages send from c# form application.I am running socket.io application as my server and c# form application as my client and used same port number on both side and given my server's Ip to c# form application in client section. I think it does not receive data because index.html first ask for nickname then it shows messages send from that user.what should I do so that first received message will be considered as user name and then remaining messages will be displayed on web page along with username.I needed username because I want to send messages from index.html to c# form application also.Please help I am trying to achieve this from like three weeks.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 C# supports TCP sockets: 
 1) You must need a IpAddress and Port number to connect. 
  Socket socket = new 
  System.Net.Sockets.Socket(System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                        System.Net.Sockets.SocketType.Stream, 
   System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[256];

            IPAddress ipAdd = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAdd, port);
            if (Session["IsPortConnected"] == null)
            {
                socket.Connect(remoteEP);
            }
         }


 If this answer helped you please mark it correct.
```

Comment: I have given my server Ip adress to form application.The problem is index.html page does not directly shows messages if nickname is not entered and I don't want that